# Relativistic Dispersion In One Space Dimension

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, fermions, topological-phase

I'm now reading [Three Lectures On Topological Phases Of Matter by
Edward Witten](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.07698) and face some statements that are unclear to me.

According to lectures: [image]

As I understand, **electronic excitations in boundary of fermi-surface  are described by continuous Hamiltonian (1.2) + (1.3).**

I am not a condensed matter physicist, so this statement is very unclear to me. Could somebody provide more detail explanation of this statement?

More concretely, **I don't understand why we can describe discrete electrons, which rules out by many-body quantum mechanics in terms of field theory and why the Hamiltonian has such form.**

Also, how to describe this system if $v=0$? As I think, one need consider quadratic terms, but what kind of Hamiltonian will describe this?

Answer (score 1):

Given your equation (1.1), we can start from a dispersion of the shape $\varepsilon(k) = k + O(k^2)$ (setting $v=1$). The context is a one-dimensional lattice model in the thermodynamic limit, which means that $k$ is defined on a compact domain: $k \in \left[ - \frac{\pi}{a} , \frac{\pi}{a} \right]$ where $a$ is the lattice spacing. This compactness in momentum space means that its dual variable is discrete. Taking the continuum limit $a\to 0$, we have the effective dispersion
$$ \varepsilon(k) = k + O(k^2) \qquad \textrm{with } k \in \mathbb R. $$
Having unbounded momentum means that its conjugate variable $x$ is now a continuous variable! Hence, we can now use the familiar substitution $k \mapsto - i \partial_x$. We thus get
$$ D_x := \varepsilon(-i\partial_x) = -i\partial_x + O(\partial_x^2) \qquad \textrm{with } x \in \mathbb R. $$
This is all that Witten used to go from Eq.(1.1) to Eq.(1.2). Note that he dropped the $O(\partial^2)$ since such higher-order derivatives are RG-irrelevant (i.e., they naturally disappear under RG flow).

Finally, to answer your question about the case $v=0$: following the same logic, the RG-dominant part would now give us $D_x = \partial_x^2$. This is also gapless and corresponds to a quadratic touching point. In other words, this is not relativistic but instead has a dynamical critical exponent $z_\textrm{dyn} = 2$.

Comment: Thank you! Could you in more details explain appearance of Hamiltonian? I understand, that this Hamiltonian gives us this energy for plane waves... **How, by knowledge of energy, construct Hamiltonian???**